# Upgrading Xserve hard drives

Tags: sata, xserve

Will 3Tb SATA hard drives work in Xserve (Model Xserve1,1) and allow all the space to be allocated.

Comment: You're probably aware that the Apple drives have custom firmware that sometimes work better with the fan control and error reporting. Just a FYI. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This may be third-hand information, from [this page of specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/xserve/stats/xserve-intel-xeon-2.0-quad-specs.html), but:

> Apple reports that this Xserve supports "any combination of SATA or SAS Apple Drive Modules: up to 2.25 TB using three 750 GB 7200 RPM SATA drive modules; or up to 900 GB using three 300 GB 15,000 RPM SAS drive modules."

Answer (score 0):

If you configured it with an Apple RAID card then no, you are limited to 2.25gb drives, but if it doesn't have a RAID card then you're fine.

https://support.apple.com/specs/xserve/Xserve_Late_2006.html

To identify your model, if you have a RAID card or not, look here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1346